# Tapestry 4.1 Hello World

Tags: tapestry

I have huge problem because I need to create project with **Tapestry 4.1**.
I cannot find any examples and I really don't know how to create project in such old version.

Could someone send me a solution how to start? I will be very grateful for that.

Answer (score 4):

Use the available maven archetype like so:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=http://tapestry.apache.org
```

And choose the 4.1 option available.

Answer (score 1):

I've google'd a bit and came across this one:

http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry4.1/tutorials/index.html

Which has:

http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Apache/Creating-Your-First-Tapestry-Project/

Also, a simple hello world:

http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry4/QuickStart/index.html

http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry4/QuickStart/helloworld.html

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find the documentation of Tapestry 4. I hope it will help you.

[Tapestry 4 documentation](http://web.archive.org/web/20120528072712/http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry4)

Answer (score 0):

**Steps to create tapestry project with command line**

Steps to create tapestry sample application =>

**STEP-1** Install the maven in your system. You must have maven to create sample project from tapestry.

**STEP-2** Once you installed the maven then run this command =>> mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=http://tapestry.apache.org

**STEP-3** When you run this command it will ask you to choose the archetype, it is will ask to enter number. You can see following log

1: http://tapestry.apache.org -> org.apache.tapestry:quickstart (Tapestry 5 Quickstart Project)

2: http://tapestry.apache.org -> org.apache.tapestry:tapestry-archetype (Tapestry 4.1.6 Archetype)

So you want to create the Tapestry 5 quickStart project then enter 1 and ***if you want to create the Tapestry 4.1.6 then enter 2.***

**STEP-4** Now according to your choice in step 3 it will show the corresponding versions in a list. For example - [Because i selected 1 that's way its showing me the version of 5] if you select 2 it will show you accordingly]

Choose version:

1. 5.0.19
2. 5.1.0.5
3. 5.2.6
4. 5.3.7

   So from this you should enter the number of the version. In this i am choosing the number 4.

**STEP-5** Now your project base is ready. Now you have to enter the some basic information of the maven project.

```
   Define value for property 'groupId': : com.sample.tapestry
   Define value for property 'artifactId': : app
   Define value for property 'version':  1.0-SNAPSHOT: 
   Define value for property 'package':  com.sample.tapestry: : com.sample.tapestry.app
```

**STEP-6** And finally it shows you Y: : 
       when shows you like this hit the enter button and you can see the logs. It will show you that build is successful.

```
   Finally your project is ready. You can delete the gradle files from the project.
   You can use git init command to initialize the git in the project.
```